# Why my Cython code is faster than C code?

Tags: python, c, cython

### Cython Code

The cython code is from [Cython document](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html).

```py
#myfunc.pyx
cdef double f(double x) except ? -2:
    return x ** 2 - x

def integrate_f(double a, double b, int N):
    cdef int i
    cdef double s
    cdef double dx
    s = 0
    dx = (b - a) / N
    for i in range(N):
        s += f(a + i * dx)
    return s * dx


#main.py
from myfunc import integrate_f
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = time.time()
    integrate_f(1,11,1000000)
    print("Cython Used Time: ", time.time() - t, " s")
```

#setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='myfunc app',
    ext_modules=cythonize("myfunc.pyx"),
)
```

Firstly, execute command in the terminal: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

Then, `python main.py`.

### C Code

#test.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

double f(double x){
    return x*x - x;
}

double integrate_f(double a, double b, int N){
    int i;
    double s;
    double dx;
    s = 0.0;
    dx = (b - a) / N;
    for(i=0; i < N; i++){
        s += f(a+i*dx);
    }
    return s*dx;
}


int main(){
    struct timeval tv_begin, tv_end;
    unsigned int  ulTime1 = 0,ulTime2 =0;
    gettimeofday(&tv_begin,NULL);
    
    integrate_f(1,11,1000000);

    gettimeofday(&tv_end,NULL);
    ulTime1 = tv_end.tv_sec*1000000 + tv_end.tv_usec;//microsecond
    ulTime2 = tv_begin.tv_sec*1000000 + tv_begin.tv_usec;//microsecond
    printf("C Used Time: %d um\n",ulTime1-ulTime2);
    return 0;
}
```

Firstly, execute command in the terminal: `gcc test.c`.

Then, `./a.out`.

### Results

```
Cython Used Time:  0.0012311935424804688 s
C Used Time: 7895 um
```

The function `f()` is called 1000000 times in both code. I thought C code should faster than Cython code, but it did not.

Comment: Have you tried to compile with [optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) turned on?

Comment: I have tried just now, but there has been little improvement in performance.
I use 'gcc -o3 test.c' and then './a.out'.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -O3 test.c`. For optimizations, it's a capital 'O'. The lowercase 'o' sets the output file, which means you have an executable called `3` now :-) You should see a little bit of difference. Double check the creation times of your files to see if you really recompiled.

Comment: I think this is an uneven comparison. Time measurement methods are not identical and despite the 1 million iterations, the measurement duration is still too short. If you want to make a fair comparison, call 1000 more to target around 1 second duration for more reliable readings. In order to use the same time measurement method, try gettimeofday at Python too.

Comment: ... or use an external time measuring tool like the `time` utility.

Comment: or even embed the time measurement part in integrate_f and return the elapsed time which makes sure that both measurements are performed in the same way.

Comment: @Crown-Messi Note that `x*(x - 1)` is numerically more stable than `x*x - x`.

Comment: Is the cython code running on 1 thread ? if integrate_f is paralellised you have your answer. This is not difficult to thread in C (breaking up the summation and doing it in parts), but your code does not do this. And does your machine have 8 cores ?

Comment: When I use "-O3" to compile the C code, the output is 0. It is normal. Thank you very much!

Comment: Compilers in optimization mode are very clever, to improve the result, it must not know the value of the variables (a and b for the integrate_f function) sent to the function. So enter them at runtime. Also it displays the result of the operation, otherwise the compiler knows that you are not doing anything with it. This both in C and in Cython.

Answer (score 1):

Potential side issue problem:

**integer overflow.**

`tv_end.tv_sec*1000000` may overflow if `time_t` is 32-bit.  Even if not on OP's machine, same code may mess up on others.

Improve and simplify time calculation.

```
// unsigned int  ulTime1 = 0,ulTime2 =0;
// ulTime1 = tv_end.tv_sec*1000000 + tv_end.tv_usec;//microsecond
// ulTime2 = tv_begin.tv_sec*1000000 + tv_begin.tv_usec;//microsecond
// printf("C Used Time: %d um\n",ulTime1-ulTime2);

long long diff_us = (tv_end.tv_sec - tv_begin.tv_sec)*1000000LL +
    (tv_end.tv_usec - tv_begin.tv_usec);
printf("C Used Time: %f s\n", diff_us/1000000.0);
```